# Increment value of integer in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So I write an app that counts amount of yellow cards in football matches through all the games of the tournament.
So let's say I count all Brazil's goals and I need to increment the amount of yellow cards with each game I go through in a loop.
So I have this dictionary cards_per_team_dictionary that looks like this:

```
['Brazil', 0]
```

and I wan't to increment the int value with each game. 
I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
def add_yellow_cards_per_team(team_name, cards_num):
    cards_per_team_dictionary[team_name] += cards_num
```

I get an error:

```
cards_per_team_dictionary[team_name] += cards_num TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

And also this:

```
def add_yellow_cards_per_team(team_name, cards_num):
    cards_per_team_dictionary[team_name] + cards_num
```

But it seems to overrun the previous integer instead of adding up to it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cards_per_team_dictionary[team_name] += cards_num` should definitely work if your dict is like `{"Brazil" 0}`. Add a runnable example that reproduces your issue

Comment: I am getting:     cards_per_team_dictionary[team_name] += cards_num
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Ok, then you have created a set somewhere , add exactly what the dict looks like.

Comment: I initiated a dictionary in the beginning of the code: 
cards_per_team_dictionary = {'Brazil', 0}

Comment: This is confusing.. your comment says {'Brazil', 0} but in your revised question you say ['Brazil', 0] which is neither a set or a dictionary -- its a list.

Comment: Perhaps it was edited by mods. It's {} here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have created a *set* not a *dict*:

```
In [4]: d = {"Brazil",0}

In [5]: d["Brazil"] += 3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-8db3ec29e78a> in <module>()
----> 1 d["Brazil"] += 3

TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

To create a dict, you add key/value pairs separated by a colon i.e  `key:value`:

```
In [6]: d = {"Brazil":0}

In [7]: d["Brazil"] += 3

In [8]: d
Out[8]: {'Brazil': 3}
```

Both a dict and set literals use `{}`, one difference being `d = {}` creates an empty dict where `st = set()` is needed to create an empty set.

If you want to add a key value pairing:

```
 d[key] = value
```

But for repeating keys you can use [dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
data = [("Brazil", 4),("Argentina",6)]
d = {}
for team, count in data:
    d.setdefault(team, 0)
    d[team] += count
```

A more efficient option is to use a [defauldict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for team, count in data:
    d[team] += count
```

In both cases if the key does not exist it is added with the new value, if it does exist the value for the key is increased.

Comment: Thanks, Padraic, how do I initialise the dictionary properly though so it knows that it's a key:value dict?

Comment: The issue is I need to add various teams to this dictionary through each iteration as the key and increase value per team if needed

Comment: d[key] = value but I think a collections.defaultdict is what you really want. I will edit in a few minutes